# Jave input class

Tags: java, class, input

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Dimension;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;

import javax.swing.JPanel;

public class Panel extends JPanel {
/**
 * 
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

final static int WIDTH = 800;
final static int HEIGHT = 600;

private int x = 40, y = 49, r = 20;

Dimension SIZE = new Dimension(WIDTH, HEIGHT);

public Panel() {
    setLayout(new BorderLayout());
    setPreferredSize(SIZE);
    setMaximumSize(SIZE);
    setMinimumSize(SIZE);
    setBackground(Color.cyan);
    setFocusable(true);
    requestFocus();
    new input(this);

}

public void paint(Graphics g) {
    super.paint(g);
    Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;
    g2.fillOval(x, y, r, r);

    repaint();
}

public int getX() {
    return x;
}

public int getY() {
    return y;
}

public void setX(int x) {
    this.x = x;
}

public void setY(int y) {
    this.y = y;
}

}

import java.awt.event.KeyAdapter;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;

public class input extends KeyAdapter {
private Panel panel;

public input(Panel panel) {
    panel = new Panel();
    panel.addKeyListener(this);
}

@Override
public void keyPressed(KeyEvent e) {
    int keycode = e.getKeyCode();

    int x = panel.getX();
    int y = panel.getY();

    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_LEFT) {
        panel.setX(x - 1);
    }

    if (keycode == KeyEvent.VK_RIGHT) {
        panel.setX(x + 1);

    }
}

}
```

I'm a Java newbie. I was trying to make a class specially for KeyListener 
but it just doesn't work. I can't figure out what I did wrong.

It might be meaningless to make a inputhandler class, and it controls only the only one class (jpanel), but i used to put all of my code in one single class.. it looks so bad. i'm learning to make them into more separate classes or make them more object-oriented~
I just confuse when to make a new class, and when not.
please help me, could you tell me what i did wrong with my code above. Was my thought wrong or just the code?

Comment: There's a different between object orientated and "look I put them in separate classes"

Comment: @AlecTeal Can you elaborate? Your comment, while true, is short and snarky and not helpful.

Comment: Sure @JohnKugelman an object should represent something you can do stuff to. The input does everything an input ought to do already. Why would you wrap around that? A big class isn't a bad thing. If I have a car I put all the car logic in it, I don't create a class called "EngineHelper" that wraps around the engine the car contains. Hope this helps.

Comment: I see. thank you   I'm always confuse about when should i make a new class.:(

Comment: @AlecTeal Although I agree this is a situation where a separate class is unnecessary, there are times that one wants an object solely just for listening. Otherwise classes such as KeyAdapter and MouseAdapter would not exist for reasons that should be obvious.

Comment: @Radiodef I agree with that too, an object should do something, even if that is just listening. But copy and pasting methods into a class because they look like they go together is not the way forward. I wish I could explain it better, but I think one must learn naturally.

Comment: Thank you all for your helpful comments. I will keep learning. thanks for helping :)

Comment: @AlecTeal It seems like you just think the OP should make his Panel class implement KeyListener instead of using KeyAdapter, which I agree with.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This looks like the first reason your KeyListener doesn't work:

```
public input(Panel panel) {
    panel = new Panel();
    panel.addKeyListener(this);
}
```

When you do this:

```
new input(this);
```

Because you are also doing this:

```
panel = new Panel();
```

You are adding the KeyListener to `new Panel()`, not the panel you are passing in to the constructor with `this`.

Personally I don't see a problem with creating a listener object just to listen, although I do not think that is necessary here.

Although presumably this will not have an effect on your listener, one other problem I see is that you are overriding paint which you should not be doing in Swing. You should be overriding paintComponent. See *Painting in AWT and Swing*: http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/painting-140037.html#callbacks

Also as far as style goes, class names start with a capital letter in Java. Your `input` class should be named `Input`.

Comment: oh,thank you. I got it. Input is working now . As for the link you gave me,  i will definitely check it out. keep learning , thanks for helping!

Comment: You're welcome. Don't forget to mark my answer as the solution if it was. : )